# Request permission dialog not showing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to request permission to READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on an Android application. My issue is that the there is no dialog displayed, thus the "onRequestPermissionsResult" is never called as well. Is there anything I am doing wrong here? I followed this link: [Developer Android](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Here is my code:

```
public class AccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected TextView changeProfileImgBtn;
    private static final int SELECTED_PICTURE = 1;
    private static final int F = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

        changeProfileImgBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accountChangeProfileImgBtn);

        changeProfileImgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AccountActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(AccountActivity.this,
                                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                         System.out.println("shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale");

                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AccountActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                F);

                        System.out.println("REQUEST");

                    }
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(i, SELECTED_PICTURE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        System.out.println("onRequestPermissionsResult");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case F: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    System.out.println("GRANTED");

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(i, SELECTED_PICTURE);

                } else {
                    System.out.println("DENIED");
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see on the Log ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(...) is called as "REQUEST" is printed. "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale" is never printed, regardless device I'm running. Neither "onRequestPermissionsResult" is printed.

```
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/System.out: REQUEST
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@ee9f27b time:106175669
```

I have included this in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Highly appreciating any help.

Comment: Perhaps your `<uses-permission>` element [is in the wrong place](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html).

Comment: It is placed inside manifest tags and outside application tags..

Comment: what is target sdk in gradle??

Answer (score 0):

Updated: Is the permission requested in your manifest? You can only request permissions that are in your manifest.

Documentation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: Yes, I have included <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in my manifest file. Uploaded it to my post now:)

Comment: Strange, I would recommend uninstalling and reinstalling, sometimes that has fixed odd permission issues for me.

Comment: Another thing to try would be adding. 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Even though you are requesting read storage, it seems like some versions of Android may have an issue related to that open.

Comment: Very strange, I have added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest as well. No success...

Comment: You might need to enable `Protect USB storage` under Developer options in the settings app on a device running Android 4.1 or higher.

Comment: @RoryHool saved the day for me. That was it for me

Answer (score 0):

use this class which use common class for all permission.

```
public class Utility1 {


public static class Utility {
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context)
    {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Use this line in your mainclass where you need to check permission.

```
 boolean result = Utility1.Utility.checkPermission(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: I ended up using this. But still the user can not accept permission from the application, so they will have to accept it from the device's settings..

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's very strange that the request permission dialog won't show up when requestPermissions(...) is called. So the AlertDialog will just have to work for now.

Comment: can u share your gradle? because in gradle target sdk version up to 23 APIthen this permission come.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have `uses-permission` within `manifest` but out of `application` section. You can even try to ask for permission even in the should show rationale block too like:

```
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(AccountActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AccountActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, F);
}
```

For more simplicity you can probably use some third party helper code, like one of my own: [PermissionHelper](https://github.com/tfKamran/android-reusable-demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/tf/reusable/demoapplication/util/PermissionHelper.java)